# log in php the remote server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Log in problem with PHP
I develop a PHP application with to 4 role based(administrator(1), caissier(2), chief(3),manager(4)) . administrator and manager use the same script and DB Query for logging , caissier other script and chief also , in local it worked fine with windows 7 as OS , Wamp server   but in remote with debian 7 and apache 2.2  only administrators are logging , all other I have  password or username incorrect, I tried to execute the query directly in the DB data are correctly retrieve 
Here my script 
For administrator and manager
PHP :

```
$managers = new Managers('PDO', PDOFactory::getMysqlConnexion());
    $manager = $managers->getManagerOf('Agent');
    $agent= $manager->LoginAdministrator($username,$pwd);
    if ($agent != null && ! $this->isConnected($agent['id'])){
        $this->setUsername($agent->Username());
        $this->setRole($agent->Id_Role());
        $this->setAgent($agent->id());
        $this->setAttribute('LastConnection', ($agent['LastConnection']));
        $this->setAttribute('Nom_Agent', ($agent['Nom_Agent']." ".$agent['PNom_Agent']));
        $manager->lastConnection($agent['id']);
        return true;
    }    return false;
```

SQL :
loginadminstrator :

```
public function LoginAdministrator($username,$pwd){
        $requete = $this->dao->prepare('SELECT Id_Agent as id,Nom_Agent,PNom_Agent,Sexe_Agent,Adresse_Agent,Telephone_Agent,Id_Role,Email_Agent,Username,Password FROM table_agent WHERE (Id_Role = 1 OR Id_Role = 4)   AND Active=1 AND Username =:username AND Password=:pwd');
        $requete->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $requete->bindValue(':pwd', md5($pwd));
        $requete->execute();

        $requete->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, '\Library\Entities\Agent');
        if ($agent = $requete->fetch())
        {
            return $agent;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

For caissier:
PHP

```
    $managers = new Managers('PDO', PDOFactory::getMysqlConnexion());
    $manager = $managers->getManagerOf('Agent');
    $agent= $manager->getByUsernameAndPWD($username,$pwd);
    if ($agent != null){
        if ( ! $this->isConnected($agent['id'])){
          if($this->isAllowed($ip,$agent['Id_Agence'])){
        $this->setUsername($agent['Username']);
        $this->setRole($agent['Id_Role']);
        $this->setAgence($agent['Id_Agence']);
        $this->setAttribute('Id_Caisse', ($agent['Id_Caisse']));
        $this->setAttribute('Id_Lieu', ($agent['Id_Lieu']));
        $this->setAttribute('Nom_Agence', ($agent['Nom_Agence']));
        $this->setAttribute('Libelle_Caisse', ($agent['Libelle_Caisse']));
        $this->setAttribute('Nom_Agent', ($agent['Nom_Agent']." ".$agent['PNom_Agent']));
        $this->setAgent($agent['id']);
        $this->setAttribute('LastConnection', ($agent['LastConnection']));
        $manager->lastConnection($agent['id']);
        return 100;
          }else{
            return 103;
          }
        }else{
            return 104;
        }

    } else{
        return 0;
    }
```

SQL

```
$requete = $this->dao->prepare('SELECT  table_agent.Id_Agent as id,Nom_Agent,PNom_Agent,Sexe_Agent,Adresse_Agent,Telephone_Agent,Libelle_Role,Email_Agent,Nom_Agence,Libelle_Caisse,B.Id_Agence,table_role.Id_Role,Id_Caisse,table_agent.Password,Username,Id_Lieu,LastConnection
                    FROM table_agent INNER JOIN table_role ON table_role.Id_Role=table_agent.Id_Role INNER JOIN (SELECT table_agence.Id_Agence, Nom_Agence,
                    Id_Agent,Date_Affectation,Id_Lieu FROM table_appartenir INNER JOIN table_agence on table_agence.Id_Agence =table_appartenir.Id_Agence WHERE Etat_Affectation=1 AND Active=1) B
                    ON  B.Id_Agent=table_agent.Id_Agent LEFT JOIN table_caisse ON table_caisse.Id_Agent=table_agent.Id_Agent
                    WHERE Username= :id AND Password=:pwd AND table_agent.Active=1 AND table_agent.id_Role=2 AND table_caisse.Active=1
                    ORDER BY table_agent.Id_Agent DESC ');
        $requete->bindValue(':id', $username);
        $requete->bindValue(':pwd',md5($pwd));
        $requete->execute();

        $requete->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, '\Library\ViewModels\AgentViewModel');
        if ($lieu = $requete->fetch())
        {
            return $lieu;
        }
        return null;
```

For Chief :
PHP:

```
    $managers = new Managers('PDO', PDOFactory::getMysqlConnexion());
        $manager = $managers->getManagerOf('Agent');
        $agent= $manager->getByChefAgenceAndPWD($username,$pwd);
        if ($agent != null){
            if ( ! $this->isConnected($agent['id'])){
                if($this->isAllowed($ip,$agent['Id_Agence'])){
                    $this->setUsername($agent['Username']);
                    $this->setRole($agent['Id_Role']);
                    $this->setAgence($agent['Id_Agence']);
                    $this->setAttribute('Id_Caisse',null);
                    $this->setAttribute('Id_Lieu', ($agent['Id_Lieu']));
                    $this->setAttribute('Nom_Agence', ($agent['Nom_Agence']));
                    $this->setAttribute('Libelle_Caisse', ($agent['Libelle_Caisse']));
                    $this->setAttribute('Nom_Agent', ($agent['Nom_Agent']." ".$agent['PNom_Agent']));
                    $this->setAgent($agent['id']);
                    $this->setAttribute('LastConnection', ($agent['LastConnection']));
                    $manager->lastConnection($agent['id']);
                    return 100;
                }else{
                    return 103;
                }
            }else{
                return 104;
            }

        } else{
            return 0;
        }
```

SQL:

```
$requete = $this->dao->prepare('SELECT  table_agent.Id_Agent as id,Nom_Agent,PNom_Agent,Sexe_Agent,Adresse_Agent,Telephone_Agent,Libelle_Role,Email_Agent,Nom_Agence,Libelle_Caisse,B.Id_Agence,table_role.Id_Role,Id_Caisse,table_agent.Password,Username,LastConnection
                    FROM table_agent INNER JOIN table_role ON table_role.Id_Role=table_agent.Id_Role INNER JOIN (SELECT table_agence.Id_Agence, Nom_Agence,
                    Id_Agent,Date_Affectation FROM table_appartenir INNER JOIN table_agence on table_agence.Id_Agence =table_appartenir.Id_Agence WHERE Etat_Affectation=1 AND Active=1) B
                    ON  B.Id_Agent=table_agent.Id_Agent LEFT JOIN table_caisse ON table_caisse.Id_Agent=table_agent.Id_Agent
                    WHERE  table_agent.Active=1 AND table_agent.id_Role=3 
                    AND Username= :id AND Password=:pwd
                    ORDER BY table_agent.Id_Agent DESC ');
        $requete->bindValue(':id', $username);
        $requete->bindValue(':pwd',md5($pwd));
        $requete->execute();

        $requete->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, '\Library\ViewModels\AgentViewModel');
        if ($lieu = $requete->fetch())
        {
            return $lieu;
        }
        return null;
```

Please help

Comment: `PDOFactory::getMysqlConnexion()` show it, is that connection PDO or mysql

Comment: WHAT IS `$this->dao->`?